# Убрать отступы по краям в области графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
wav = wave.open("/var/www/2333_fixed.wav", mode="r")
(nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname) = wav.getparams()
 
duration = nframes / framerate
w, h = duration*20, 150
k = int(nframes/w*2)
DPI = 80
content = wav.readframes(nframes)
samples = np.frombuffer(content, dtype=types[sampwidth])
plt.figure(figsize=(float(w)/DPI, float(h)/DPI), dpi=DPI)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=0.99, top=0.990, wspace=0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot(samples[0::k])
plt.savefig("/var/www/spectrm.png", dpi=DPI)
```

Не удается убрать отступы слева и справа

Сейчас имею следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если играться с

> plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=0.990)

Вроде и выравнивает, но, как ни играйся с отступами, не выходит. Например:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=0, top=0.990)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m.py", line 21, in <module>
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=0, top=0.990)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2394, in subplots_adjust
    return gcf().subplots_adjust(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2385, in subplots_adjust
    self.subplotpars.update(left, bottom, right, top, wspace, hspace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 202, in update
    raise ValueError('left cannot be >= right')
ValueError: left cannot be >= right
```

Comment: Если изображение имеет большую ширину, соответственно и данные отступы более.

Comment: Нашел решение  `plt.margins(0)`